# hazelcast-kubernetes Network Discovery: How to use with Multiple Nodes

Tags: java, kubernetes, networking, hazelcast, device-discovery

We have a Kubernetes cluster which spins up 4 instances of our application.  We'd like to have it share a Hazelcast data grid and keep in synch between these nodes.  According to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes the configuration is straightforward.  We'd like to use the DNS approach rather than the kubernetes api.

With DNS we are supposed to be able to add the DNS name of our app as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/v1.0.6/cluster/addons/dns).  So this would be something like myservice.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local.

The problem is that although we have 4 VMs spun up, only one Hazelcast network member is found; thus we see the following in the logs:

```
Members [1] {
    Member [192.168.187.3]:5701 - 50056bfb-b710-43e0-ad58-57459ed399a5 this
}
```

It seems that there aren't any errors, it just doesn't see any of the other network members.

Here's my configuration.  I've tried both using an xml file, like the example on the hazelcast-kubernetes git repo, as well as programmatically.  Neither attempt appear to work.

I'm using hazelcast 3.8.

---

Using hazelcast.xml:

```
<hazelcast>
  <properties>
    <!-- only necessary prior Hazelcast 3.8 -->
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
  </properties>

  <network>
    <join>
      <!-- deactivate normal discovery -->
      <multicast enabled="false"/>
      <tcp-ip enabled="false" />

      <!-- activate the Kubernetes plugin -->
      <discovery-strategies>
        <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
            class="com.hazelcast.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">

          <properties>
            <!-- configure discovery service API lookup -->
            <property name="service-dns">myapp.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local</property>
            <property name="service-dns-timeout">10</property>
          </properties>
        </discovery-strategy>
      </discovery-strategies>
    </join>
  </network>
</hazelcast>
```

Using the XmlConfigBuilder to construct the instance.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
XmlConfigBuilder builder = new XmlConfigBuilder();
builder.setProperties(properties);
Config config = builder.build();
this.instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

---

And Programmatically (personal preference if I can get it to work):

```
Config cfg = new Config();

NetworkConfig networkConfig = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
networkConfig.setPort(hazelcastNetworkPort);
networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
networkConfig.setPortCount(100);

JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);

DiscoveryConfig discoveryConfig = joinConfig.getDiscoveryConfig();
HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory factory = new HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory();

DiscoveryStrategyConfig strategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(factory);
strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns", kubernetesSvcsDnsName);
strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns-timeout", kubernetesSvcsDnsTimeout);

discoveryConfig.addDiscoveryStrategyConfig(strategyConfig);
this.instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```

---

Is anyone farmiliar with this setup?  I have ports 5701 - 5800 open.  It seems kubernetes starts up and recognizes that discovery mode is on, but only finds the one (local) node.

Here's a snippet from the logs for what it's worth.  This was while using the xml file for config:

```
2017-03-15 08:15:33,688 INFO [main] c.h.c.XmlConfigLocator [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2017-03-15 08:15:33,917 INFO [main] c.g.a.c.a.u.c.HazelcastCacheClient [HazelcastCacheClient.java:112] CONFIG: Config{groupConfig=GroupConfig [name=dev, password=********], properties={}, networkConfig=NetworkConfig{publicAddress='null', port=5701, portCount=100, portAutoIncrement=true, join=JoinConfig{multicastConfig=MulticastConfig [enabled=true, multicastGroup=224.2.2.3, multicastPort=54327, multicastTimeToLive=32, multicastTimeoutSeconds=2, trustedInterfaces=[], loopbackModeEnabled=false], tcpIpConfig=TcpIpConfig [enabled=false, connectionTimeoutSeconds=5, members=[127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1], requiredMember=null], awsConfig=AwsConfig{enabled=false, region='us-west-1', securityGroupName='hazelcast-sg', tagKey='type', tagValue='hz-nodes', hostHeader='ec2.amazonaws.com', iamRole='null', connectionTimeoutSeconds=5}, discoveryProvidersConfig=com.hazelcast.config.DiscoveryConfig@3c153a1}, interfaces=InterfacesConfig{enabled=false, interfaces=[10.10.1.*]}, sslConfig=SSLConfig{className='null', enabled=false, implementation=null, properties={}}, socketInterceptorConfig=SocketInterceptorConfig{className='null', enabled=false, implementation=null, properties={}}, symmetricEncryptionConfig=SymmetricEncryptionConfig{enabled=false, iterationCount=19, algorithm='PBEWithMD5AndDES', key=null}}, mapConfigs={default=MapConfig{name='default', inMemoryFormat=BINARY', backupCount=1, asyncBackupCount=0, timeToLiveSeconds=0, maxIdleSeconds=0, evictionPolicy='NONE', mapEvictionPolicy='null', evictionPercentage=25, minEvictionCheckMillis=100, maxSizeConfig=MaxSizeConfig{maxSizePolicy='PER_NODE', size=2147483647}, readBackupData=false, hotRestart=HotRestartConfig{enabled=false, fsync=false}, nearCacheConfig=null, mapStoreConfig=MapStoreConfig{enabled=false, className='null', factoryClassName='null', writeDelaySeconds=0, writeBatchSize=1, implementation=null, factoryImplementation=null, properties={}, initialLoadMode=LAZY, writeCoalescing=true}, mergePolicyConfig='com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy', wanReplicationRef=null, entryListenerConfigs=null, mapIndexConfigs=null, mapAttributeConfigs=null, quorumName=null, queryCacheConfigs=null, cacheDeserializedValues=INDEX_ONLY}}, topicConfigs={}, reliableTopicConfigs={default=ReliableTopicConfig{name='default', topicOverloadPolicy=BLOCK, executor=null, readBatchSize=10, statisticsEnabled=true, listenerConfigs=[]}}, queueConfigs={default=QueueConfig{name='default', listenerConfigs=null, backupCount=1, asyncBackupCount=0, maxSize=0, emptyQueueTtl=-1, queueStoreConfig=null, statisticsEnabled=true}}, multiMapConfigs={default=MultiMapConfig{name='default', valueCollectionType='SET', listenerConfigs=null, binary=true, backupCount=1, asyncBackupCount=0}}, executorConfigs={default=ExecutorConfig{name='default', poolSize=16, queueCapacity=0}}, semaphoreConfigs={default=SemaphoreConfig{name='default', initialPermits=0, backupCount=1, asyncBackupCount=0}}, ringbufferConfigs={default=RingbufferConfig{name='default', capacity=10000, backupCount=1, asyncBackupCount=0, timeToLiveSeconds=0, inMemoryFormat=BINARY, ringbufferStoreConfig=RingbufferStoreConfig{enabled=false, className='null', properties={}}}}, wanReplicationConfigs={}, listenerConfigs=[], partitionGroupConfig=PartitionGroupConfig{enabled=false, groupType=PER_MEMBER, memberGroupConfigs=[]}, managementCenterConfig=ManagementCenterConfig{enabled=false, url='http://localhost:8080/mancenter', updateInterval=3}, securityConfig=SecurityConfig{enabled=false, memberCredentialsConfig=CredentialsFactoryConfig{className='null', implementation=null, properties={}}, memberLoginModuleConfigs=[], clientLoginModuleConfigs=[], clientPolicyConfig=PermissionPolicyConfig{className='null', implementation=null, properties={}}, clientPermissionConfigs=[]}, liteMember=false}
2017-03-15 08:15:33,949 INFO [main] c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2017-03-15 08:15:33,960 INFO [main] c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8] Picked [192.168.187.3]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2017-03-15 08:15:34,000 INFO [main] c.h.system [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Hazelcast 3.8 (20170217 - d7998b4) starting at [192.168.187.3]:5701
2017-03-15 08:15:34,001 INFO [main] c.h.system [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2017-03-15 08:15:34,001 INFO [main] c.h.system [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2017-03-15 08:15:34,507 INFO [main] c.h.s.i.o.i.BackpressureRegulator [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Backpressure is disabled
2017-03-15 08:15:35,170 INFO [main] c.h.i.Node [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Creating MulticastJoiner
2017-03-15 08:15:35,339 INFO [main] c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationExecutorImpl [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Starting 8 partition threads
2017-03-15 08:15:35,342 INFO [main] c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationExecutorImpl [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2017-03-15 08:15:35,351 INFO [main] c.h.c.LifecycleService [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] [192.168.187.3]:5701 is STARTING
2017-03-15 08:15:37,463 INFO [main] c.h.system [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Cluster version set to 3.8
2017-03-15 08:15:37,466 INFO [main] c.h.i.c.i.MulticastJoiner [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [192.168.187.3]:5701 [dev] [3.8] 


Members [1] {
    Member [192.168.187.3]:5701 - 50056bfb-b710-43e0-ad58-57459ed399a5 this
}
```

Comment: I've heard about some DNS issues before, what's the reason you prefer DNS over namespace discovery? Did you try to use the API based one already? Did this work?

Comment: Yes we did try it using the service. Apparently we cannot have access to the service at the moment because it's under development by the kubernetes team. We don't want to / can't wait.

Comment: What do you mean "it is under development"? It was ready before the DNS service was out of "experimental".

Comment: @Matt just wondering if you resolved this issue and if so, what was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with service dns name as:

myapp.mynamespace.endpoints.cluster.local

Please reply it's work or not and also post your full log.

Comment: The other question, are you sure "myapp" and "mynamespace" is correct? You have to set it to the real values :-)

Comment: Yes You are right that will be real values , I just added as example. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda happened long time ago. But the problem here was using wrong class name for discovery strategy.

It should be `com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy`